# Does 'as' keyword in C# only converts Object type variables to the type I desire?

Tags: c#

From the official C# document, I learnt that I can convert from one type to another using the 'as' keyword. However, when I tested it out, it seems like things are not working as it is supposed to (please correct me if I am wrong). When I convert an Object type variable or if the types have "has-relation" (inheritance), then it works fine. But, if I try to convert two different types that are does have a "has-a-relation", then the IDE (visual studio 2019) gives me an error (instead of return null). Please correct me if I am wrong or something I am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person();

        Animal animal = person as Animal; // the IDE shows an error under "person as Animal"
    }
}

class Person
{ }

class Animal
{ }
```

Thank You very much for your response.

Comment: Do you have a link to the part of the documentation that suggest that incompatible types should yield a `null`?

Comment: The IDE is trying to warn you that it will always return null because the types are unrelated.

Comment: What makes you think you can turn a `Person` into an `Animal`?  In your example they do not share the same base class (`object` not included).  `null` is correct behaviour in this case.  If you instead tried to cast you would encounter a runtime error

Comment: Please go and read this to understand how to cast and why this doesn't work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: @stickybit, here is the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

Comment: @DavidG, thanks for the link. I have read it and I don't think I have any problem in with the concept of casting. However, I have just stepped into the realm of "as" and "is" keyword (or operator) in c#.

Comment: Well you obviously still don't understand it because you are trying to cast `Person` to `Animal`.

Comment: In this article from MSDN, it explicitly says...

"The as operator explicitly converts the result of an expression to a given reference or nullable value type. If the conversion is not possible, the as operator returns null. Unlike the cast operator (), the as operator never throws an exception."

So, I was wondering that the use of "person as Animal" won't raise any exception, but assign null to "animal" variable.

Comment: *"If the conversion is not possible, the as operator returns null"*

Comment: @DavidG, would you mind reading this article, the "as operator" part...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

Comment: I did and that quote above is from that section. Did you read it?

Comment: @DavidG, yes, I have. So, I was expecting animal variable to be assigned to null.

Comment: So you understand *"If the conversion is not possible, the as operator returns null"*?

Comment: @DavidG, Ahh, I think so...

Answer (score 2):

This is because the IDE analyzes your code and knows that it's not possible to cast Person into Animal.

This code wouldn't give you an error and return null instead:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object person = new Person();

        Animal animal = person as Animal;
    }
}

class Person
{ }

class Animal
{ }
```

Note, it will still tell you that this expression will always be null, but it won't be classified as an error.

The reason for this is because Person and Animal are two specific types that are known not to be compatible, however the Object type can contain anything and it's not immediately clear whether it's an incompatible type or not.

Answer (score 0):

If Animal is not Person or these two classes not inherit same parent?

Comment: Are you asking a follow-up question or asking more information?